# BigQuery and Logs Analysis Query 'Grouping by expressions of type STRUCT is not allowed' even when casting field to string

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use the GCP logs analysis feature to get a breakdown of all log events in a logging bucket.

The fields I'm querying from the logs bucket dataset are:

```
log_name      STRING
json_payload  JSON
```

To ensure I'm working with all `STRING` data types, I select out the fields that I need into a temp table and query the temp table.

```
WITH log_breakdown AS (
  SELECT log_name,
         STRING(json_payload['@type']) AS log_type
  FROM myorg.global._Default._AllLogs
  WHERE timestamp > TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
)
```

Per the below, all fields are of type `STRING`.

```
SELECT * FROM log_breakdown
```

But, if I try to group by `log_type`, I get the `Grouping by expressions of type STRUCT is not allowed` error.

```
SELECT log_name,
       log_type,
       COUNT(log_type) AS event_count
FROM log_breakdown
GROUP BY (log_name, log_type)
ORDER BY event_count desc
```

If each field in the temp table is of type `STRING`, why would I still get this error?

How can I aggregate on `log_type` to get a breakdown of my json_payload log events?

Comment: using `(log_name, log_type)` makes it implicitly of type struct - just remove `(` and `)` and use `GROUP BY log_name, log_type`

Comment: Hi @user797963, did the above comment help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Mikhail Berlyant, the issue can be resolved by using `(log_name, log_type)` that makes it implicitly of type struct . You can remove `(` and `)` and use [GROUP BY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#group_by_clause) `log_name, log_type`.